# Flutter how to convert String to List<String>

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this `String`.

```
  var String a = '["one", "two", "three", "four"]';
  var ab = (a.split(','));
  print(ab[0]); // return ["one"
```

I want to convert this to `List<String>`.
The problem is it returns square bracket too. I want to List looks this `["one", "two", "three", "four"]` not `[["one", "two", "three", "four"]]`.
How can I convert this properly?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your string looks like a valid JSON, so this should work for you:

**New (proper generic type**

```
import 'dart:convert';
...

var a = '["one", "two", "three", "four"]';
var ab = json.decode(a).cast<String>().toList();
print(ab[0]); // returns "one"
```

**Old**

```
import 'dart:convert';
...

var a = '["one", "two", "three", "four"]';
var ab = json.decode(a);
print(ab[0]); // returns "one"
```

Comment: how to do if list is not a valid JSON

Comment: Then you need to parse the string with custom code.

Comment: How can I get the length of `ab`?

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/List/length.html `ab.length`

Answer (score 6):

```
void main(){
     String listA = '["one", "two", "three", "four"]';
     var a = jsonDecode(listA);
     print(a[0]); // print one

     String listB = 'one,two,three,four';
     var b = (listB.split(','));
     print(b[0]); // print one
}
```