# Flutter: How to Convert String of List to List of String?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've my List as "["Monday", "Tuesday"]". But I want it as ["Monday", "Tuesday"]. How to convert it?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288553/flutter-how-to-convert-string-to-liststring

Comment: @jitsm555  That's not helpful, actually. because I'm parsing this data to the API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to convert String to List<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288553/flutter-how-to-convert-string-to-liststring)

Comment: No actually, I'm passing this data to the API. So, that answer is not useful