# How to convert string to list and get the length of the list in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, converters

I want to convert a string to a list and get the length of the list. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52288553/16124033) and quoted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288579/16124033). But there is a problem, when I use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52288579/16124033)'s code, I can only use the index to get the item, and I can't read the whole list and get the length of the list.

My code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
…

final String list = '["a", "b", "c", "d"]';
final dynamic final_list = json.decode(list);
print(final_list[0]); // returns "a" in the debug console
```

How to convert string to list and get the length of the list? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `final_list` is a `List` so you don't need to convert it anymore

Comment: just call (json.decode(list) as List).length

Comment: Hi @pskink you are right

Comment: Hi @eamirho3ein, this can be a solution

Comment: @eamirho3ein can you answer this question and share your solution to let other users know it's not just a solution (there are three answers, but two of them say the same solution, one of them doesn't do what I expected, no any answer about your solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusion and you might want to clarify it a bit more. Nevertheless, you can try to explicitly convert the decoded result to a `List` like so:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

final String list = '["a", "b", "c", "d"]';
final final_list = json.decode(list).toList();// convert to List
print(final_list[0]); // returns "a" in the debug console
print(final_list.length); // returns 4
print(final_list); // returns: [a,b,c,d]
```

> However, without explicit conversion, `final_list` should still return `4`. Hence, my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

**The easy and best way is here.**

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final String list = '["a", "b", "c", "d"]';
  final List<String> finalList = List<String>.from(json.decode(list));
  print(finalList.length.toString());
}
```

Comment: it is worth mentioning that, although ok, this is not the recommended way. Here you already have an implicit type inference through the `List<string>.from()`. There fore no need to explicitly typedef the variable. Also, it is recommended to use `.toList()` rather than `List.from` which is better readability.
once again this is just for a bit of contextual clarification ;)

Answer (score 1):

After converting your string it will return you a list, try this:

```
final String list = '["a", "b", "c", "d"]';
int _length = (json.decode(list) as List).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```
void main() {
  var string = 'Hello, World!';
  // make string into a list with map
  var list = string.split('').map((char) => char).toList();
  print(list);
  print(list.length);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I want